# How do you set Helm CLI env variables on windows?

Tags: windows, kubernetes-helm

If you use the Helm CLI tool it has a set of environment variables. For example on a command line type `helm env` and it will show a list of helm specific variables.

How do these get set and what command or where can I go to change them on a windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can use the `setx` command to override the default Helm environment variables.

For example `setx HELM_NAMESPACE my-namespace` will create a local user environment variable in windows that will override the default HELM_NAMESPACE value used by the tool. For the tool to use the changed value you must open up a new CLI.

You can validate that a new CLI is required by running the `helm env` in the CLI where setx was executed and then running the `helm env` in a new CLI. The values will be updated in the new CLI, but not in the original CLI.